# "message": "Undefined property: $response", dingo api with laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to implement dingo API with laravel 5.2

Following is a function which I have written for testing dingo

```
public function profile()
{
    try {
        $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->toUser();
        if (!$user) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'User Not Found'], 500);
        }
    } catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $ex) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Something went wrong'], 500);
    }
    //return response()->json(['user' => $user->with('profile')->where('id', $user->id)->first()], 200);
    return $this->response->array($user->toArray());

}
```

It works fine when I use

```
    return response()->json(['user' => $user], 200);
```

But when I use following line of code in accordance with dingo syntax. It shows error

```
    return $this->response->array($user->toArray());
```

Basically none of the dingo defined functions work. How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you using the dingo helpers? From the [documentation](https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Responses)

> The response builder provides a fluent interface to easily build a
>   more customizable response. The response builder is generally used in
>   conjunction with transformers.
>
> To utilize the response builder your controllers should use the
>   Dingo\Api\Routing\Helpers trait. To save importing and using the trait
>   on all your controllers you can simply create a base controller that
>   all your API controllers will extend.

```
use Dingo\Api\Routing\Helpers;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class BaseController extends Controller
{
    use Helpers;
}
```

Comment: Somehow application was unable to find the address of the BaseController. Same has been resolved and hence dingo syntax are working now. Thanks.